# Reading and writing error pajek file in Networkx

Tags: networkx

I am receiving error when I write to a pajek file and then read back the same file using Networkx library python

```
   >>> G=nx.read_pajek("eatRS.net")

   >>> nx.write_pajek(G,"temp.net")

   >>> G1=nx.read_pajek("temp.net")

Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
 File "<string>", line 2, in read_pajek
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/networkx/utils/decorators.py", line 193, in _open_file
   result = func(*new_args, **kwargs)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/networkx/readwrite/pajek.py", line 132, in read_pajek
   return parse_pajek(lines)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/networkx/readwrite/pajek.py", line 168, in parse_pajek
splitline=shlex.split(str(next(lines)))
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/shlex.py", line 279, in split
  return list(lex)
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/shlex.py", line 269, in next
token = self.get_token()
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/shlex.py", line 96, in get_token
  raw = self.read_token()
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/shlex.py", line 172, in read_token
r aise ValueError, "No closing quotation"
 ValueError: No closing quotation
```

Answer (score 0):

Creating a graph within networkx, writing in pajek format and then back again works fine for me. E.g. with `gnm_random_graph`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as np
n = 10
m = 20

G = nx.gnm_random_graph(n,m)
nx.write_pajek(G, "temp.net")
G1 = nx.read_pajek("temp.net")
```

Only if I edit the intermediate graph to have, say,

```
"vertex one 0.3456 0.1234 box ic White fos 20
```

do I get the `ValueError: No closing quotation` error you have.  Node labels can be numeric or string, but if they include spaces, the name must be quoted.From the [Pajek manual](http://vlado.fmf.uni-lj.si/pub/networks/pajek/doc/draweps.htm):

> label - if label starts with character A..Z or 0..9 first blank determines end of the label
>   (example: vertex1), labels consisting of more words must be enclosed in pair of special 
>   characters (example: "vertex 1")

---

Thus, I suggest that you inspect your input file "eatRS.net".  Perhaps there is an issue with character encoding, mismatched quotes (e.g. opening with `"` and closing with `'`), or a line break within the node label?